# PHP RegEx Conditional returning false

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing

I am attempting to write a RegEx to parse a small bit of HTML in order to wrap the first letter of a stort in a dropcap span. The problem is, ocassionally our writers will place images (which are floated right) before the first letter in a story. I thought that I could write a RegEx with a conditional that checks for the extra div, and changes what it searches for.

This is where things get weird.

Here is the text I am testing on (has an image):

```
<p><div id="attachment_28554" style="width: 415px" class="wp-caption alignright"><img class="size-full wp-image-28554 " alt="Caniff_MissMIzzou[1]" src="http://cafnrnews.com/uploads/2014/04/Caniff_MissMIzzou1.jpg" width="405" height="716" /><p class="wp-caption-text">A Milton Caniff drawing of Miss Mizzou. Courtesy the Toni Mendez Collection, The Ohio State University Billy Ireland Cartoon Library and Museum.</p></div>She was tall, blond, tough yet vulnerable, lived with her sketchy past, and was never seen without her signature trench coat. From her beginning in 1952 to her passing in 1988,</p>
<p>she was more than the pen-and-ink drawings of the other women, for she inspired calendars, airplane pin-ups, beauty contests and halftime events on the MU campus.</p>
```

Here is the RegEx I wrote: `(<p><)?(?(1)<\/div>|>)(\w)`

Now the first matching group of my RegEx looks for `<p><` because that's how I determine whether or not there is an image before the first paragraph or not. The strange thing is, even though `(<p><)` by itself matches, the conditional returns false.

Testing: http://regex101.com/r/vS5cM0

The expected output is `S` but it matches the first letter of the first paragraph (`A`) instead (meaning the conditional returned false.

I understand that an XML parser would be the right thing to do, but that seems extreme to find one letter and wrap it in a div.

Comment: It may seem extreme, but HTML can be extreme. What if your `<p>` becomes `<p class="whatever">`?  Or the `<div>` tag spans multiple lines? The reason so many people say "use an HTML parser" is because we've been down this road before and run into the same hassles you're going to run into.

Comment: This regex should give you the first letter of your text, no matter if there's an attachemen `<div>` in between or not:  `(<\/p><\/div>(\w))|(<p>(\w))` But such solutions tend to fail miserably as soon as the HTML is changed a little bit.

Comment: @AndyLester Thank you, I think that is what we will end up doing.

Comment: @z80crew Please post as an answer so I can accept.

Comment: @z80crew Also, your RegEx can be written as `(<\/p><\/div>|<p>)(\w)` to avoid as many capturing groups, but thank you for pointing out I didn't have to use a conditional I just needed an OR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex should give you the first letter of your text, no matter if there's an attachement `<div>` in between or not:

```
(<\/p><\/div>(\w))|(<p>(\w))
```

It matches the first letter after a `</p></div>` sequence or the first letter after an opening `<p>` tag. But such solutions tend to fail miserably as soon as the HTML is changed a little bit. So, add a class or an id to the `<p>` tag and the regex will stop matching. For stable solutions an HTML parser would be the better way to go.

Answer (score 1):

It may seem extreme to use an HTML for what seems like a simple task, but HTML can be extreme. What if your `<p>` becomes `<p class="whatever">`? Or the `<div>` tag spans multiple lines? The reason so many people say "use an HTML parser" is because we've been down this road before and run into the same hassles you're going to run into.

Answer (score 0):

The first p element is an unclosed element.
That is an invalid html code. Soon or later you must fix that... and maybe, all work ok.

Comment: This is just a small part of the entire HTML.

Comment: Look the code... in the first line, the second p is open before the first p was be closed... If U close the first p, the regexp will be easy.